# Inserting data into SQLite database

Tags: android

When I insert data into database it works fine on Emulator. But when I insert it using a real device I get an error. My sample code is:

On button click event:

```
btn_subcat_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String subcat_name = ed_subcat_name.getText().toString();
        if (subcat_name.trim().length() == 0 || image_add.getTag() == d) {
            showDialog(0);
        } else {
            long subcat_idauto = db_add_subcat.insertSubCategory(
                        subcat_name, id, bmp_default);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sub category added",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Id", ""+id);
            if (subcat_idauto != -1) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

On restart of previous activity inserted data should be display. So I have written,

```
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    custom_adapter.clear();
    if (custom_adapter.isEmpty()) {
        custom_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    checkMyReceipe();
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Your logcat output will be helpful.

Comment: post your log, please

Comment: It doesn't display any error.When i click on save button it display toast.But in listview it display something new item that i have not added.

Comment: please post code of db_add_subcat.insertSubCategory(
                        subcat_name, id, bmp_default);

Comment: @Stefan Be public long insertSubCategory(String name, int id, Bitmap bm) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
  byte[] bArray = baos.toByteArray();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(COL_SUBCAT_NAME, name);
  values.put(COl_SUB_ID, id);
  values.put(COL_SUBCAT_IMAGE, bArray);
  values.put(COL_SUBCAT_MYRECEIPE, 1);
  Log.e("IdInsert", ""+id);
  long i = getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_SUBCAT, null, values);
  return i;
 }

Comment: it is better to update your question...